# How to have multiple values in phpmyadmin column?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I would like to know how to have multiple values in a column for row. In this case, multiple access numbers for users so that I can retrieve those numbers for page access.

What I have now:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  |  first_name  |  last_name  |       email       |  password  |  date  |  access  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  Test        | User        |  test@website.com | md5pass    | -date- | 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to give the user multiple access codes/variables/integers.

Like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  |  first_name  |  last_name  |       email       |  password  |  date  |  access  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  Test        | User        |  test@website.com | md5pass    | -date- | 2, 201, 3908
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible??

And upon retrieving it, if possible, how would I go about that?

I plan on doing something like: if user access code '201' exists, then give access/show content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're going about it *can* work; just explode and trim the `access` column out when you retrieve the user row.

However, the right way to do it is to have a different table, like user_access. At its simplest, that'd look like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_access (
  user_id int,
  access int
)
```

This table would have one row per access code defined, per user. Here's what your example would look like in the table:

```
select * from user_access;
+---------+--------+
| user_id | access |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      2 |
|       1 |    201 |
|       1 |   3908 |
+---------+--------+
```

Then, when you retrieve the user and you're interested in their access level, you'd join against the user_access table:

```
SELECT u.*, ua.access FROM users u LEFT JOIN user_access ua on u.id = ua.user_id WHERE u.id = <some user id>
```

(left join, because there's no guarantee that the user has any access defined)

Or, do it in two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = <some user id>
SELECT access FROM user_access WHERE user_id = <some user id>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I see how that could work. Although, how would you add multiple access numbers in the access column??

Comment: Using the separate-table strategy, you don't need to. Using the two-query thing above, the second query will return all of the access numbers that were defined for that user. This makes adding or removing new access super easy: just add or remove a row from the table.